# Monitor file changing doesn't works for database file with systemd

Tags: database, mariadb, systemd, inotify

I want to monitor one file of database in filesystem under this below path:

```
/var/lib/mysql/mydatabase/onetable.idb
```

I set a systemd service, but it doesn't recognize if the file changed. If I modify this file, nothing happend, but if the permission modified, it works. I tried to monitor this file with inotifywait as well, but I got same result.

As I know the systemd run as root, so I think there is not any permission problem. The path is 100% sure valid, because I can list the file directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Temporary solved this issue by insert this code in crontab:

```
*/3 * * * * test "`sudo find /var/lib/mysql/mydatabase/onetable.idb -mmin -4`" && /etc/myscript.sh
```

It's not permanent solution, because I want to do this trigger based script run.

Answer (score 0):

From the inotify.7 manpage:

```
   The inotify API does not report file accesses and modifications that
   may occur because of mmap(2), msync(2), and munmap(2).
```

These routines are frequently used in database implementations.

Comment: If the inotify doesn't support it, which software should I use?